# How do I use Dataframe apply function to normalize Data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to normalize new data with the mean and std values which I already have got.

```
t = np.array([[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6],
     [7,8,9]])

tt = np.array([[1,1,1],
     [100,100,100]])

a = pd.DataFrame(t, columns=['a','b','c'])
b = pd.DataFrame(tt, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'], index=['mean', 'std'])

def standardize(x, y):
    return (x - y.loc['mean']) / y.loc['std']
```

[image: 'a, b Dataframe ']

```
a.apply(standardize(a,b))
```

I want to get normalized dataframe that each values is calculated by 'b' dataframe's mean and std on each columns with apply function

ex) a[0]['a'] = (a[0]['a'] - b['mean']['a']) / b['std'][a]

any better ways would be fine as well. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have it. Do `standardize(a,b)` instead of `a.apply(standardize(a,b))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(a-b.loc['mean'])/b.loc['std']
```

If you define `b` as `b=b.T`, then

```
(a-b['mean'])/b['std']
```